# Tag Iframe doesn't work after click Anchor in HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, iframe, htmlunit

everyone!
I'm learning working with HtmlUnit. I'm with a problem.
When I click in a anchor my page has a iFrameTag that doesn't load.
The oficial page work normal.

Follow part my code:
--Head
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

```
    CookieManager cookieManager = client.getCookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    client.setCookieManager(cookieManager);

    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
```

--End Head

```
    (...)
    HtmlAnchor linkEdital =  (HtmlAnchor) pageEdital.getByXPath("//a[@data-acao='edital']").get(0);
    pageEdital = linkEdital.click();
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
    System.out.println(pageEdital.asXml());
```

But, the variable pageEdital doesn't change.

I thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the page your are using public?

Comment: Hi @RBRi how are you? Yes, the link is: https://www.peintegrado.pe.gov.br/portal/Mural.aspx

Comment: I click at a line in grid and open other page. Here, there is a link (anchor) "Edital" that when I click load a iframe.
But I'm trying and can't to do work.

Comment: I'm fine, hope the same for you. I will try to help, please open an issue on github and provide a bit more code. I will than have a look.

Comment: From i first look i think the element you like to click is not visible. In the case HtmlUnit ignores the click() call (only writes a hint to the log)

Comment: @RBRi First I would like thanks by atencion. 
When I use the debug code and click in the anchor the log show me: (2021-04-14 15:40:21.933  INFO 2068 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] .g.h.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController : Re-synchronized call to https://www.peintegrado.pe.gov.br/portal/WebService/Servicos.asmx/PesquisarResumoEdital).
But this tag ( <iframe id="frameResumoEdital" src="" width="800px" height="425px">
</iframe>) doesn't update.

Before I forget I'm use the 2.48 version.

Comment: @RBRi I open the issue in github. The number is #341. There I put print's, log's, steps and part of my code. My friend thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the iframe is not included per default, you have to look inside yourself.

This works here (maybe you can lower the wait times)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED)) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.peintegrado.pe.gov.br/portal/Mural.aspx");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20_000);

        DomNodeList tds = htmlPage.getElementsByTagName("td");
        HtmlTableDataCell td = (HtmlTableDataCell) tds.get(1);
        td.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20_000);

        HtmlAnchor linkEdital = (HtmlAnchor) htmlPage.getByXPath("//a[@data-acao='edital']").get(0);
        linkEdital.click();
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20_000);

        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.println(htmlPage.asXml());
        System.out.println("********************");

        // dig into the iframe yourself
        HtmlInlineFrame iframe = (HtmlInlineFrame) htmlPage.getElementById("frameResumoEdital");
        HtmlPage iPage = (HtmlPage) iframe.getEnclosedWindow().getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.println(iPage.asText());
        System.out.println("********************");
    }
}
```

For more details look at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/341

Comment: I'm sorry! But I need you help! There is another page similar this problem that you help me a get tag Iframe. But this new page when always show a error: 
2021-05-05 12:51:05.265 ERROR 1858 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] c.g.h.j.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener   : Error during JavaScript execution
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: innerText is read-only for tag 'html' (https://compras.cetiqt.senai.br/Portal/Scripts/portaljs1?v=Ei-iqWxCMWoSqcf1vkTQ_kcBnknTwdegoFEvCAf9vgc1#1)

Comment: Again, can you please open an issue... will have a look.